# Query regarding approach to solve a fluid kinematics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, flow

**Question:**

Someone is washing their car, using a nozzle similar to the one sketched in the figure. The nozzle is 9.91 cm long, with an inlet diameter of 1.07 cm and an outlet diameter of 0.460 cm. The volume flow rate through the garden hose (and through the nozzle) is V = 0.0530 L/s, and the flow is steady. Estimate the magnitude of the acceleration of a fluid particle moving down the centerline of the nozzle.

[image]

**How I attempted to solve**

Since volume flow rate is constant,
$\frac{dV}{dt} = const=c$

$A*v=c$

$-v*\frac{dA}{dt}+A*\frac{dv}{dt}=0$

$A*a = v*\frac{dA}{dt}$

Which on simplification gives

$a = \frac{c*(dA/dt)}{A^2}$

Solving at x=9.91 cm gives a=45.1 m/sq.sec

While the answer is 49.6 m/sq.sec

**Real Question**

The author uses average velocity

$a=\frac{(v_(out)^2 - v_(in)^2)}{2*∆x}$

I am not sure about two things - is my approach correct at all? If yes then which approach mine or author's is *more accurate*? Is there any different intuitive approach?

**Note:**

This is not a *homework* type question since the op is not asking for any answer but is curious regarding their approach to solve the problem and is hoping to gain insight.

The question is taken from fluid mechanics fundamentals and applications, fourth edition, Cengel and Cimbala, published by Mc Graw hill (version for Indian subcontinent only). Example no 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key word here is "estimate".  It is not hard to see that the acceleration of a water molecule along the center line is not constant as it passes through the nozzle, so there is not one particular preferred value of the acceleration.

However, it is reasonable to assume (and can be justified more rigorously if needed) that the acceleration magnitude will not change by more than one order of magnitude over the passage through the nozzle.  This means that we can calculate several different numbers to use as an "estimate" of the acceleration, any one of which could be reasonable:

1. The acceleration just after a particle enters the nozzle
2. The acceleration when a particle is halfway through the nozzle
3. The acceleration just before a particle exits the nozzle
4. The acceleration averaged over the distance of the path through the nozzle
5. The acceleration averaged over the time that the particle is in the nozzle

I *think* your method corresponds to method #3 (I will confess that I don't quite understand it, particularly how you found a number for $dA/dt$.)  Meanwhile the "official" solution corresponds to method #4.

Any one of these numbers is justifiable as an "estimate".  That said, on an intuitive level I would probably prefer #2 or #5.  Assuming that the acceleration varies monotonically through the nozzle, #1 & #3 will end up being the highest or lowest value of the acceleration, rather than somewhere in the middle of the range.  I would also prefer #5 over #4 because it would have a nice interpretation:  if $\bar{a}$ is the time-averaged acceleration, rather than the distance-averaged, then force being exerted on the water to keep the nozzle in place would just be $F = m \bar{a}$, where $m$ is the mass of the volume of the water in the nozzle.